# db.collection in firebase what is db here

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
db.collection("users").doc("frank").set({
  name: "Frank",
  favorites: {
    food: "Pizza",
    color: "Blue",
    subject: "Recess"
  },
  age: 12
}).then(function() {
  co
```

Answer (score 0):

The `db` variable is initialized as shown in the documentation on [initialzing Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize) as:

```
// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '### FIREBASE API KEY ###',
  authDomain: '### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###',
  projectId: '### CLOUD FIRESTORE PROJECT ID ###'
});

var db = firebase.firestore();
```